# Remove get_template_part() from custom theme

Tags: filters, get-template-part

I am creating my own theme and was wondering if there is a way to remove `get_template_part()` when you're on a specific page? For example:

```
<?php
if ( is_page('blog') ) {
 [Remove]get_template_part('the', 'blog');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do it the opposite way:

```
<?php
if ( !is_page('blog') ) {
 get_template_part('the', 'blog');
}
?>
```

this would make it show up on all pages but the blog.

Comment: Gosh @rudetek. I feel so retarded right now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ha.  no worries.  would you mind marking it as answered?  (check box to the left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

So I can think of a couple of ways at least:

1. You could make a [new template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) in your theme, that doesn't use `get_template_part`, and assign that template to pages you create in WP. (solution for multiple pages of the same type)
2. You could create a [single-use template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-page) for just this page, (based on its slug) so that just this page has a special template that doesn't use `get_template_part`

Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes. I am aware of these methods. However, my curiosity is the one that needs to be fed. I want to know if there is a way of doing it in the method I am talking about.

Comment: I'm not sure what method you are talking about then, sorry? Which method are you talking about?